# COM-Addin does not load in Outlook 2010x64 (LoadBehavior set to 2). How to debug "runtime error"?

Tags: delphi, debugging, 64-bit, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have an addin that is written in Delphi XE3/XE4, using the Add-in-Express framework (i.e. not .NET, no VSTO). It is running fine in all 32bit-versions of Outlook **as well as the 64bit-version of Outlook 2013**. However, under the 64bit-version of Outlook 2010 it simply will not load: The COM-Addin manager tells me "Not loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM-Add-in." (i.e. the LoadBehavior-value in the registry got set to 2).

Is there any way to find out what that "runtime error" might be?

I have already put `OutputDebugString`s all over my code as well as the VCL and ADX code and not a single one of those appears to ever be reached at all before Outlook unloads the DLL again.

When running in the debugger (via PAServer) any breakpoints I set (e.g. on the `begin` of the DPR-file or in the `initialization` of the `Classes` unit) do not even ever get enabled. Seems to me the DLL is never even loaded into the debugger (this does work fine with Outlook 2013x64).

I also already wrote a dummy host EXE that would instantiate my COM server and call the appropriate methods on the `IDTExtensibility2`-interface to simulate the actual Outlook host but no errors occur in that case either.

Looking at things with Process Monitor, the addin DLL gets loaded briefly but then immediately gets unloaded again and then the LoadBehavior value is reset.

I checked the Application logs and enabled logging in Outlook itself but so far no hints to the nature of the supposed "runtime error".

All latest updates and service packs were applied to all of Delphi, Add-in-Express, Outlook, Windows. The Windows version is 7 Pro. No other addins are installed.

Any more ideas on what to check?

Comment: Add-in express support is excellent

Comment: Yes, I know, but seeing that the flow of execution never even reaches the ADX-code before it fails, I don't really think ADX could be part of the problem... I only included it for completeness' sake and to clarify that this is not a VSTO addin.

Comment: Cut stuff out of your add-in until it loads. All the same, I'd still try ADX support.

Comment: @David: I now actually went the other way and created the absolute bare-bones minimum addin: a COM-DLL with a single automation object, implementing `IDTExtensibility2` and nothing else in it (also no ADX - all in all, very similar to this example: http://ogware.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/creating-com-addins-with-delphi-part-1/). As with the full-size addin, this will immediately get deactivated by Outlook 2010x64 on load. I can verify this on two independent VMs. The problem appears to be more fundamental than even I had thought so far... :(

Answer (score 1):

Add an environment variable VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS value 0 to that PC that is causing the problem.
Then u can reload the addin from outlook >> options >> Addins >> Manage.
So outlook will try reloading this addin and u will get a popup window with details of the prob...

Comment: You did notice I explicitly mentioned this is **not** a VSTO addin? That said, I already tried the environment variable nevertheless but no effect...